# Eclipse IDE: linking OpenGL Libraries (C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, opengl, libraries

After weeks of trying endlessly to link some libraries to Eclipse, I have come to no solution. While I am not getting an error, when I press run, a dialog pops up and says that "OpenGL32Test.exe has stopped working" (OpenGL32Test, by the way, is the name of my Eclipse project). The following code is what I tried to compile, but it simply will not create the black window and red square it should (the code was taken from https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/HowTo_OpenGL_C.html#mingw_glut a website that I tried to follow):

```
#include <windows.h>  // For MS Windows
#include <GL/glut.h>  // GLUT, includes glu.h and gl.h

/* Handler for window-repaint event. Call back when the window first appears and
   whenever the window needs to be re-painted. */
void display() {
   glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color to black and opaque
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);         // Clear the color buffer

   // Draw a Red 1x1 Square centered at origin
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
      glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);    // x, y
      glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f);
      glVertex2f( 0.5f,  0.5f);
      glVertex2f(-0.5f,  0.5f);
   glEnd();

   glFlush();  // Render now
}

/* Main function: GLUT runs as a console application starting at main()  */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   glutInit(&argc, argv);                 // Initialize GLUT
   glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Setup Test"); // Create a window with the given title
   glutInitWindowSize(320, 320);   // Set the window's initial width & height
   glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50); // Position the window's initial top-left corner
   glutDisplayFunc(display); // Register display callback handler for window re-paint
   glutMainLoop();           // Enter the infinitely event-processing loop
   return 0;
}
```

I complile the program WITH linked libraries, I went to:

> Project Properties => C/C++ Builds => Settings => Tool Settings =>
>   MinGW C++ Linker

and I added the library files freeglut, glu32, and opengl32. The program simply will not run. Also, in the:

> C/C++ General => Paths and Symbols => Libraries tab

I have the 3 libraries linked. Please help me figure out why my program simply won't run! Is it because I messed up linking the files? I'm running on Windows and using MinGW, but I know I'm linking the libraries, because the program successfully builds, and the console line seems right:

> g++ -o OpenGLtest.exe main.o -lfreeglut -lglu32 -lopengl32

I placed all the necessary lib files and header files needed for this program to run in the MinGW root directories where they belong (the include/GL folder, and the lib folder). What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Basically, I wasn't using .dll's correctly. In windows, Dynamic libraries are libraries with the .dll extension. By putting the .dll in the same directory as the .exe executable, the program is able to run.

Answer (score 0):

1. so I once did this same tutorial and got it to work I think with out having to copy over the dll....

Add “-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++” as Linker flags for your new project. This text should be added to the Linker flags field, which can be found by right-clicking on the new Project in the Project Explorer and clicking on Properties. Under the Project Properties, expand the C/C++ Build menu and click on Settings. Under the Tool Settings tab, expand the MinGW C++ Linker menu and click on Miscellaneous. Add the text to the Linker flags field, then click the Apply button.

That worked then but when I tried it tonight it didn't work as nicely :-\

2. but in the instructions for the lab it DOES say to copy the dll over to the MinGW bin directory.. another name for a .dll is a shared library...

"Download, unzip and copy header files from "include\GL" to "MINGW_HOME\include\GL"; the libraries from "lib" to "MINGW_HOME\lib", and ***shared library from "bin" to "MINGW_HOME\bin"*** (which should be included in the PATH environment variable), where MINGW_HOME is the MinGW installed directory."